# R and Metatrader 4

Tags: r, metatrader4

R has a great way of collecting data from other sources (eg Yahoo finance etc)

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("YHOO",src="google")
```

Is there a way of collecting Metatrader 4 into R

eg:

```
library(*******)
getSymbols("***",period=1hr, src="Metatrader4")
```

Comment: `getSymbols("YHOO",src="google")` donwload data from [this url](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ%3AYHOO&ei=-aCgUdDuCuT3wAOBEA). if Metatrader offer the same free service it is easy to implement this source but obviously it is not a free service. So the answer is probably you can't collect data from Metatrader source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give MQL2R a try, it's my new opensource project to allow exactly this

https://code.google.com/p/mql2r/

Comment: What does mql2r do that mt4r cannot do?

Answer (score 3):

This thread will certainly help you: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-and-Metatrader-td1693168.html.